# Can someone explain meaning of `# __unicode__ on Python 2` in Django documentation

Tags: python, django

```
# __unicode__ on Python 2
```

Django newbie here, I have tried to search for the meaning of this comment above but couldn't find information about it.

**In the Django documentation I find this comment in many parts of the code , does that mean that this section is only if I use Django with Python 2 or it means something else ?**

I mean functions like this

```
def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
            return "%s the place" % self.name
```

In this Example code:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the place" % self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(
        Place,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the restaurant" % self.place.name

class Waiter(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the waiter at %s" % (self.name, self.restaurant)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the sample code is written in Python 3, and that if you are writing a Python 2 application, you should replace `__str__` with `__unicode__` in your class definitions.

Python 2 and 3 differ in many aspects, particularly in how unicode and strings are handled.

Comment: Thank you for illustration Alex